# How to avoid a lot of if else if conditions when there is creation of object with different values

Tags: java, enums, refactoring

I have a Four different enum UserOneStatus, UserTwoStatus, UserThreeType and UserFourType which has ID and Name

I have to filter the User based on the those Enum ID's so, I end up with the following code

```
if (ChoosenUserFilterValue.equals(String.valueOf(UserOneStatus.REQUESTED.getId()))) {
            selecedUserFilter = new UserFilter(UserOneStatus.class,
                    String.valueOf(UserOneStatus.REQUESTED.getId()),
                    UserOneStatus.REQUESTED.getUserStatus(), String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID()));
        } else if (ChoosenUserFilterValue.equals(UserOneStatus.ACTIVE.getId() + "")) {
            selecedUserFilter = new UserFilter(UserOneStatus.class,
                    String.valueOf(UserOneStatus.ACTIVE.getId()),
                    UserOneStatus.ACTIVE.getUserStatus(), String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID()));
        } else if (ChoosenUserFilterValue.equals(UserOneStatus.INACTIVE.getId() + "")) {
            selecedUserFilter = new UserFilter(UserOneStatus.class,
                    String.valueOf(UserOneStatus.INACTIVE.getId()),
                    UserOneStatus.INACTIVE.getUserStatus(), String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID()));
        } else if (ChoosenUserFilterValue.equals(UserTwoStatus.REVOKED.getId() + "")) {
            selecedUserFilter = new UserFilter(UserTwoStatus.class,
                    String.valueOf(UserTwoStatus.REVOKED.getId()),
                    UserTwoStatus.REVOKED.getLoginStatus(), String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID()));
        } else if (ChoosenUserFilterValue.equals(UserThreeType .ADMIN.getId() + "")) {
            selecedUserFilter = new UserFilter(Some.class,
                    String.valueOf(UserThreeType.ADMIN.getId()),
                    UserThreeType.ADMIN.getName(), String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID()));
        } else if (ChoosenUserFilterValue.equals(UserFourType .SSO_TEMPLATE.getId() + "")) {
            selecedUserFilter = new UserFilter(Some.class,
                    String.valueOf(UserFourType.SSO_TEMPLATE.getId()),
                    UserFourType.TEMPLATE.getName(), String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID()));
        }
```

I refactored It little bit but I could't able to get the results as same as the upper code

The refactored code is as follows

```
Map<String,Class<?>> map = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
map.put(UserOneStatus.REQUESTED.getId()+"", UserOneStatus.class);
map.put(UserOneStatus.ACTIVE.getId()+"", UserOneStatus.class);
map.put(UserOneStatus.INACTIVE.getId()+"", UserOneStatus.class);
map.put(UserTwoStatus.REVOKED.getId()+"", UserTwoStatus.class);
map.put(UserThreeType.ADMIN.getId()+"", Some.class);
map.put(UserFourType.TEMPLATE.getId()+"", Some.class);

String key ="";

if(map.containsKey(ChoosenUserFilterValue)){
    Class<?> getSelectedUserFilterValueClass = map.get(selectedUserFilterValue);

     for (Entry<String, Class<?>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                key = entry.getKey();
        }

    selecedUserFilter = new UserFilter(getSelectedUserFilterValueClass, key , getSelectedUserFilterValueClass.toString(), String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID());
}
```

any suggestions are appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Any reason why you can't use a `switch` statement here?

Comment: Polymorphism, State machines... Those would be the things to look into. Just refactoring will not lead to significant improvements.

Comment: @ GhostCat  I thought about state machines but its nothing to deal with events and state transfer, please let me know if I'm missing something. Its just check the value and create new UserFilter object according to the value.

Comment: @ Makoto `switch` works but i have  a hard time to write a test cases and cover all the branches. Thanks for the reply though

Comment: Do you want to avoid the conditions? I'm thinking in something more clear to read but with the same number of conditions.

Comment: @reos Yeah. My main intention is to avoid conditions

Answer (score 0):

Problems of creating objects of one interface/abstract class, based on some kind of input data (like ids, numbers, etc.) are supposed to be solved using factory method design pattern, or abstract factory pattern. Your code is a kind of factory method, and using if/else statements are perfectly fine in such situations. Here you can check an example of [factory method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm), and [abstract factory](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/abstract_factory_pattern.htm).